# How can I set KDevelop to compile codes with gcc properly?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, kdevelop

I just downloaded KDevelop from Ubuntu Software Center, and have gcc.

I want to see anything happens by pressing F9 but KDevelop says I need to configure a launcher first. And all I know about the setting window is I have to put 'gcc' in somewhere on the window, as well as path to the source code file and path to the executable file it will make.

I have no any knowledge about this window, no any syntax to use in it and can't find it anywhere on the web. Now I desperately require some help. **I want to make KDevelop to compile and debug with already-installed gcc and gdb.**

[image: Configuration Window.]

Answer (score 0):

It asks you of which executable to debug. You, i suppose, don't want to debug `gcc`, so you should set this field to your executable. You can also select `Project Target` option, and choose CMake target that corresponds to your executable.

Comment: Should the executable to debug be set on the 'Debug' section on the left? And I want to set the global compile option, so I think the executable should be gcc. I want to make it so if I press 'run' or 'build', gcc is called and compile my source code (even if it's not included in a project).

Answer (score 0):

This step happens after the build step. Make sure your build process is working first (F8).

The window above lets you select which executable in your project should be run when the launch button is pressed.

If your project is created in KDevelop or otherwise uses CMake as the build system, this should be configured by default and use the "target" part of the dialog.

Otherwise the executable should point to the executable you created as part the build process that you want to test.